# How to use cursor in graphql?

Tags: mongodb, graphql

Is there any easy way to use the cursor in GraphQL while fetching data from MongoDB or the basic cursor which is commonly using in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page can be used to solve the cursor issue in mongodb, we can (new PageRequest(environment.getArgument("Start"), environment.getArgument("Size")));
however the PageRequest is deprecated